# Modal for a full 'description' field

Tags: text, modal-dialog

I have a site that I have developed that allows visitors to submit/upload their own entries.

They fill in a form to do so, which then gets outputted onto the site.

One of the fields is a 'description' field. This is a text area of any length.

When outputting this on the site, it obviously has an effect on the design, as one entry might have 2 sentences as a description, and another 10 paragraphs.

I'm looking for the best way to make these a bit more uniform, and I am considering limiting the output of the description field to 2-3 sentences and then any more will have a link to open the full description field in a modal.

What do you think are the pro's and con's of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modal is a wrong tool for your task. The con's of modal is:

- **Breaking the flow.** Modal breaks the user flow as it is perceived as new interaction wich requires thinking, learning, decisions and actions. So user switches from the reading task to recognition task.
- **Invasion.** Modals are frequently used as advertisement tool or some widget, which is non-relevant to users' task (new-style banners). So some users will close it without reading to continue reading task.
- **Lack of context.** As the text is a part of an entry, modal breaks the whole picture, displaying text without context.
- **Cognitive load.** In a modal user should find the starting point, i.e. part of text he didn't read yet. It's creates cognitive load and time loss.
- **Accessibility.** Modal usage in your case isn't good from assessibility point.

Instead of modal, you could use familiar way of coping with the large amount of text:

[image]

---

> When outputting this on the site, it obviously has an effect on the
>   design

People will visit your site for content, not for design. **Design which limits content isn't good.**

Comment: All good points. I did think that a modal might be pushing it and the reasoning above confirms that.  I will be going the 'read more' route! Many thanks.